# Expression Bodied method performance (return new instance via factory method vs cached reference)

Tags: c#

I'm wondering if there is any performance difference between an expression bodied method that returns a static list or when using a cache List variable.

Consider this code

```
// expression body
private static List<Guid> GetList() => new()
{
    new Guid("f93b8c93-3084-4087-8727-dad436fe5b76"),
    new Guid("6894046e-1deb-4128-b639-aa472f7f95d3")
    // many more 
};
```

vs cache the list and then return it

```
// create the list
private static readonly List<Guid> CacheList = new()
{
    new Guid("f93b8c93-3084-4087-8727-dad436fe5b76"),
    new Guid("6894046e-1deb-4128-b639-aa472f7f95d3")
    // many more
};

// return the list
private static List<Guid> GetList()
{
    return CacheList;
}
```

Will the expression bodied method result be compiled only the first time GetList() is called or will the expression be compiled each time the GetList() method is called?

thanks

Comment: Yes, there will be a difference. One will construct a new list each time, the other will return the same instance to a pre-existing list instance each time. Bear in mind that if someone does `GetList().Add(...)`, that will do different things in each case: modifying a copy just used by that caller, vs modifying the copy used by everyone

Comment: Why not compare apples with apples, and do `private static List<Guid> GetList(){ return new()
{
    ...
};` otherwise, what are you comparing, really? You're changing two factors and asking which one is faster: AB is faster than CD, but nothing to do with the A/C part, and solely to do with the B/D part, yet you're asking about the A/C part

Comment: I agree with canton7's analysis - but to address the final paragraph of the question, it's not a matter of the expression-bodied member being *recompiled*. It's only compiled at compile-time. Are you perhaps getting confused with expression trees, which can be "compiled" at execution time? Your expression-bodied example is exactly equivalent to a block-bodied method with "return new() { .... }` as the body.

Comment: (This has nothing to do with expression bodies btw. `private static List<Guid> GetList() { return new List<Guid>() { ... }; }` would do the same as your first sample, and `private static List<Guid> GetList() => CacheList;` the same as the second)

Comment: If you're interested in knowing what code looks like after compiled/"what is the difference between", SharpLab can help: https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwCwG5nJQDMmM6AwugN7Lp3oAOATgJYBuAhgC4CmmcANnQAZFgGcuAHgDiAVxbAAfOmk8uoiQFEAQgAoAlOgC8ygHY8A7gdr0aSeg/TmLK+cF0AiAGYBOIgCMADgBjPwBaIlRA7DDsKIB2MMD4mETgDmBsIgEvHgBWf3iBD30AGhtHJ0tXBU8BQJ847AEeMLhgHn9YuBhAsP8BIh8wjg5sFK943zzgIhKKxwB6RfQAWw5TAE81gHsmPgWAX3x7egXmdm4+LCENKTkFZVV1cS4DO0q6KHiqlzuZNyKBYOD6fBzOGrubx+IKhIgRKIxOLJJIpNIZLI5fKFYplYGfCEPKH1RqoZqtdqdbq9fqDYajcYwSbTWbzU5gujLNYbbarPYHdmOY5HZCHIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private static List<Guid> GetList() => new()
{
  new Guid("f93b8c93-3084-4087-8727-dad436fe5b76"),
  new Guid("6894046e-1deb-4128-b639-aa472f7f95d3")
  // many more 
};
```

This will create a new list each time you call the `GetList` function. i.e, making changes to this list after calling the `GetList` will apply just to this instance and will not apply to other instances who called the `GetList` function.

```
private static List<Guid> GetList()
{
  return CacheList;
}
```

The `GetList` method in this example will return the same instance for everyone calling this function. i.e, modifying this list will apply the changes to whoever called this function and asked for that particular instance.

In terms of performance, there is no difference between regular function to expression body. It's a pure syntactic sugar added in C# 6.0. That means it compiles to the same IL code and there is absolutely no difference in performance.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the direct performance impact of `newing` the List on the heap and adding items to it on each call, there's also the less obvious impact of all these 'copies' of the list which then need to be collected by the GC sometime later.

But in addition to performance, there's another consideration

```
private static List<Guid> GetList() => new() ...
```

Is essentially a factory method, returning a mutable (but copied) collection. The caller is then free to add new elements to the collection, without affecting any other code which might have obtained its own 'copy'.

Whereas

```
private static readonly List<Guid> CacheList = new()
{...};

private static List<Guid> GetList()
{
    return CacheList;
}

// OR
private static List<Guid> GetList() => CacheList;
```

Both return a reference to the same, static shared mutable collection. (`readonly` means that the `CacheList` field is not reassignable, it doesn't change the fact that `List<T>` is mutable)

This might be fine for your purposes, since the field and the method are both `private`.
However, this isn't a good practice to expose mutable static collections as `public` fields or methods. Consider a caller:

```
var theList = myClass.GetList();
theList.Add(Guid.NewGuid()); // << Mutation
```

This change will affect all observers of the shared `CachedList`, and in fact if multiple callers attempt the change this code will have thread safety issues. Because the underlying field is also static, the changes to the list will persist for the lifespan of the process, which can lead to insidious bugs.

So, when exposing publically 'cached' fields, I would always ensure that the fields are fully immutable, e.g.

```
private static readonly IReadOnlyCollection<Guid> CacheList = new List<Guid>
{
    ...
};

// Ensure that public accessors restrict mutability
public static IReadOnlyCollection<Guid> GetList() => CacheList;
```

Callers won't be able to add / remove elements from the shared cached list, and so this will be thread safe, performant, and memory efficient at the same time.